# MSBuild warnings (MSB4011 and others) when building Delphi 10 project group

Tags: delphi, msbuild

In Azure DevOps I have created a yaml build script that uses the `MSBuild@1` task to build a Delphi 10.2 Project Group file.

For every project in the group, i get the following MSBuild warning:

`##[warning]C:\delphi\19.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(0,0): Warning : Expected configuration file missing - C:\WINDOWS\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\EnvOptions.proj`

For the first project in the group I also get this warning:

`##[warning]Project1.dproj(639,5): Warning MSB4011: "C:\delphi\19.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Build\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.160.1\_work\1\s\Projects\Project1.dproj (511,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored.`

I have no idea to fix these warnings, they are coming from the target files that are provided by Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first occurs, probably because Delphi was installed in different user from where the agent was setup. Make sure Delphi and agents are on the same account.

The second one, occurs, because in the *.dproj file, you have duplicate lines, referring to "\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets". Make a search and you will find them. Just keep one of them.

I just had the same problems, and solved them, as described.

Comment: You are right, the agent was running under the NetworkService account, while Delphi was not installed using that account. I let the agent run under the same account as Delphi was installed with, and now the first warning has gone. The other warning was indeed caused by multiple <Import> lines. I remove the ones without a condition in it, the ones with a condition I left in the file (`<Import Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets" Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')"/>`)

Comment: Another reason for the first error might be that the IDE has never been started under that user account before. Apparently the directory under %AppData% only gets created when the IDE is started, not by the installer.